# Odd lists comparison result

Tags: python, list

I have encountered strange things when I tried to compare one list to another. It may be not related but I am currently writing code for python 2.7. I do not remember for sure, but I am almost certain that in python 3.3 and 3.4 list comparison did not behave like that.

```
>>> b = ['look', 'at', 'table']
>>> c = ['look', 'at']
>>> b[0:1] == c
False
>>> b[0:1] == c[0:1]
True
```

Why the result of the first compassion is 'False', but the second result gives 'True', but it seems that both of them should give 'True'.

Comment: `c[0:1]` gives you the items from 0th to 1st index, which is just 1 item while c has 2 items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the interactive interpreter :

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38)
>>> b
['look', 'at', 'table']
>>> c
['look', 'at']
>>> b[0:1]
['look']
```

So `c` and `b[0:1]` are different.

You'll find more information about this if you look up online for documentation about slice operators.

Comment: How did I miss that, such an amateur mistake, I feel really embarrassed.